# How to get task instances for upstream tasks by their task_id in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

Is it possible to somehow extract task instance object for upstream tasks from context passed to `python_callable` in `PythonOperator`. The use case is that I would like to check status of 2 tasks immediately after branching to check which one ran and which one is skipped so that I can query correct task for return value via xcom.

Thanks

Comment: Alternative suggestion: would it instead make sense to have two separate operators (one for each branch) so you don't have to check the status of the previous task instance?

Comment: Perhaps you are correct. However, I'm not looking for real world problem solution as I'm just writing some examples while educating myself on the topic of airflow. Also, as a counter-example to what you proposed: In case of having to execute same chain of operators regardless of branching outcome, I'd have a lot of non-dry code (lot of copy/paste). Ofcourse, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think that's fair, definitely isn't an answer to your question. You could avoid copy pasting by using a for loop or some python functions to generate each branch given some configuration, though.